# Instagram API - Json response undefined index

Tags: php, json, instagram

I would like to get the "urls" to the images of a instagram pages through json response.

This is how my code looks, but I always get the error message: "Undefined index: images"
Can someone help me? :)

```
<?php


        // Get data from Instagram User
        $url        = "https://www.instagram.com/wsj/media/";
        $instagramdata  = @file_get_contents($url);
        $instagramdata  = json_decode($instagramdata, true);



    {  

    $instagramfeed = $instagramdata['items']['images']['standard_resolution']['url'];

    }

    ?>

    <div class="instagramfeed">

    <?php echo $instagramfeed;  ?>

    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Items in the Instagram API are an array of objects, indexed by integers.

To get the URL of the first image, you will need to use

```
$instagramfeed = $instagramdata['items'][0]['images']['standard_resolution']['url'];
```

Note my addition of `[0]` to tell PHP that we want the first item in the array of items (in most languages, arrays start at 0, not 1). You can vary the number to read different images.

To get the URLs of each of the images, you can loop through the items with a foreach (or some other kind of loop structure).

```
foreach($instagramdata['items'] as $item) {
    echo $item['images']['standard_resolution']['url'];
}
```

Best of luck.